# Getting formGroup object from node

Tags: angular

Can I get `formGroup` object from parent (grandparent) element?

Example html:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div>
    <app-input></app-input>
  </div>
</form>
```

I know that I can get parent element - but how to get `formGroup` object?
I know also that I can use `databinding` or `service` but getting from parent is best approach for me.

Comment: Inject parent directive in child constructor

Answer (score 0):

Simply do

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div>
    <app-input [FG]="form"></app-input>
  </div>
</form>
```

And declare an input in your child

```
@Input() FG: FormGroup;
```

Comment: I know I can use databinding. Looking for other solution.

Comment: Well I don't know what you expect, the FormGroup is an Angular variable. If you want to get it with native JS, then good luck

Comment: I'm asking if it is possible